# Comparing two datasets in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm looking to compare two datasets with each other.  In an ideal world, I'd like to have it to show a green item if the data matches between the two. I have created two different GDocs files to get the code out there, to prevent SO from dinging me on formatting.

The first dataset is from our program itself, it pulls everything from our application, and displays the information, based on company code.  The second dataset is from an external source requiring validation.  The main fields I am matching are "NPI Number (Type 1)" from DS1 vs. "NPI" from DS2. If there is a match to highlight in green the row from both sides of data.

[Dataset 1](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I4L1pMs1Pnj_PULyHA3bqwXlTG_qiHoNpFPXygUupUQ/edit?usp=sharing)

[Dataset 2](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q6ZQ8pPGxw6_NYqmVAoA-oUvN-txppa-0PXkowlqvAY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: what report item are you using to show up the data from these datasets?

Comment: Sorry, Provider Name, NPI (Unique Item), NPI Type, Taxonomy Code, and Enrollment Status.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [LookUp function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function) and set that as a expression to fill the background color of a text box or row of a table

Sample Expression: =iif(Len(Lookup(Fields!NPI.Value, Fields!NPI.Value, Fields!ProviderName.Value, "DS1"))>0,"Green","Red")

I have created a sample [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxGB_gOmE_mhWm55aUw4ZnBVU2M?usp=sharing). Download entire content and run it.